# Finding consecutive rows above a certain value

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a sports statistical database. In one of the tables, I have the game-by-game stats for each player.

```
PK, PlayerID, OpponentID, GameID, Points, Rebounds, etc...
```

I would like to know how to return queries like, most consecutive games with at least 20 points or consecutive games with 10 rebounds, etc... (I have many other tables where this applies as well, just using this as an example.)

GameID is in chronological order, so that would be the way to determine consecutive games.

I assume this involves CTEs but I am not well-versed in that subject.

Comment: hmm.. no.. CTEs aren't necessary here. Although you could do an implementation using them I sure..  I wouldn't use them for anything other then recursion expressions.

Comment: @BrettCaswell, I presume you are referring specifically to `Recursive CTE` and not the normal `CTE` right ?

Comment: hmm.. I'm not familiar with any distinction beyond the act of doing a recursive operation.  I'll look into that

Comment: anyhow.. @abyss616 can you clarify what you mean "return queries like".  That is, it seems like you're asking for someone to provide you a query... you'll need to provide a code sample reflecting your attempt... otherwise, it appears as though you're requesting code be provided.. i.e. a code service.. that would make this question off-topic..

Comment: You have ask very general question. Wht is  consecutive game in your biz rule and data both ?Suppose a player has 35 points with 8 consecutive game another person has 50 points with only 5 consecutive game. you hv to provide data and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for queries that implement solutions for gaps-and-island problems.

Your question is quite generic, so let me give you an example of a such query, say: find the player(s) with the most consecutive 20+ point games; also find out the first and last game of the series, and the top/low points.

Here is a query for that purpose:

```
select top 1 with ties
    PlayerID,
    min(GameID) first_game,
    max(GameID) last_game,
    min(Points) min_points,
    max(Points) max_points,
    count(*) consecutive_games
from (
    select
        s.*,
        row_number() over(partition by PlayerID order by GameID) rn,
        sum(case when Points >= 20 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by PlayerID order by GameID) sm
    from PlayerStats s
) x
where Points >= 20
group by PlayerID, rn - sm
order by consecutive_games desc;
```

This works by doing a conditional sum ordered by game, that increments for each game above 20 points, and comparing it to the game sequence. When the difference between the sum and the game sequence changes, a new group of games starts; the rest is just aggregation. You can run the subquery idenpendently to see what it returns; you can also remove the `top 1` clause to see the whole list of +20 points games series).

With this sample data:

```
PlayerID | GameID | Points
-------: | -----: | -----:
       1 |      1 |     10
       1 |      2 |     25
       1 |      3 |     24
       1 |      4 |     32
       1 |      5 |      2
       1 |      6 |     27
       1 |      7 |     42
       1 |      8 |     32
       1 |      9 |     21
       1 |     10 |     20
```

The query returns:

```
PlayerID | first_game | last_game | min_points | max_points | consecutive_games
-------: | ---------: | --------: | ---------: | ---------: | ----------------:
       1 |          6 |        10 |         20 |         42 |                 5
```

You should be able to apply the same logic for other stats.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0770f4fd14c5597a4dc7566ea47f7816)**